# Finding what elements are in a 2-D array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find what elements are in a 2-D array, such as something along the lines below:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,0,0],[1,3,0],[2,7,4]])
print find_element(a)
[0,1,2,3,4,7]
```

Is there a function that would do this for me?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,0,0],[1,3,0],[2,7,4]])
>>> np.unique(a)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7])
```

Comment: Thank you very much m(_ _)m The np.unique function is just what I was looking for.